# Bootstrap dropdown jumps to top left when scrolling with overflow auto

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have encountered this strange issue where the dropdown will jump to the top left if scrolling with `overflow: scroll` or if it's bigger than the body.

I'm trying to "dynamically" change a dropdown button to an input on keypress, and have it share the same dropdown box. The content of the dropdown changes as you type.

I think it's better to illustrate the issue by showing a direct example, (because it's a bit big): https://jsfiddle.net/eno4v9kL/

The issue occurs if you scroll down, and then start typing something. It will then jump to the top left.

[image: The issue]

I have kind of tried to control the behavior of the dropdown but I don't understand how it should be handled;

```js
dropdown = new bootstrap.Dropdown(elm);
```

---

I'm not quite sure how to handle this properly in JavaScript, because bootstrap initializes the dropdown automatically. How does one control this automatic behavior?

I think a possible solution would be to have 2 dropdowns, one for each element instead of sharing the same dropdown, but I would like to only use this one dropdown if possible

Comment: As soon as I click the "All" dropdown in your fiddle, it gives a "Script error." on the console, and nothing else happens.

Comment: Hmm, I get the error aswell `Uncaught TypeError: i.createPopper is not a function` and I don't know why it shows that. It works for me in both firefox and chromium

Comment: @CBroe I updated the JSFiddle now. This one doesn't have the error

Comment: And what steps do we have to take now to see the problem? Even if I add content at the end of body so that there is something to scroll, I can't see the behavior you are talking about. (Testing in a Chromium-based browser.)

Comment: Refresh/re-run, click the button, scroll to the bottom, and then type something. I see it's behaving a bit different on chromium than firefox (it shouldn't enter double letters)